# Why is nickel-56 not a stable nuclide?

Tags: radioactivity, nuclear-chemistry, radiochemistry

> Why is $\ce{_{28}^{56}Ni}$ not a stable nuclide?

As far as I studied radiochemistry, magical numbers of protons and neutrons correspond to the more stable elements, due to their perfectly spherical form: $2,$ $8,$ $20,$ $28,$ $50,$ $82$ and $126.$ Double magic nuclei are those with both $Z$ and $A - Z$ magical, like $\ce{_2^4He},$ $\ce{_8^{16}O},$ $\ce{_{82}^{208}Pb}.$ All of these end points of decay series and very stable elements.

However, $\ce{_{28}^{58}Ni}$ seems to be favored, alongside $\ce{_{28}^{61}Ni}$, instead of the more obvious choice $\ce{_{28}^{56}Ni}$. What is the reason?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_nickel#Notable_isotopes

Comment: After calcium-40, elements start to deviate from initially ideal 1:1 nucleon ratio, as more neutrons are needed for the most stable isotopes of the element.  1:1 iron-52 is not stable either.

Comment: @Poutnik iron-52 1:1 does not have the double magic property

Comment: I am well aware of it. But there is multiple factors determining the isotope stability. In this case ratio 1:1 is already out of the [valley of stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_of_stability) , what beats the effect of magical numbers. Tin-100 is double magic number isotope too, but the lightest stable isotopes are tin-112(observationally stable) and tin-114.

Comment: You might want to search around in the physics stack exchange. Lots of related stuff, like this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/460464/313612. Or just ask over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all stable nuclei with a "magic" number of protons or neutrons are "doubly magic". Perhaps they would be (actually the same number of protons and neutrons) if only internuclear forces were acting within the nuclei, but in practice electromagnetic forces become increasingly important as we move to heavier nuclei. The competition between electromagnetic and internuclear forces leads to stable isotopes generally not being the most "magical" with respect to internuclear forces alone. For example, with 50 as the magic number:

- Zirconium-90, the most abundant isotope of that element, has 50 neutrons but only 40 protons.
- Tin forms several relatively abundant (>10%) isotopes with 50 protons but 66, 68 or 70 neutrons.

Given this circumstance, the fact that lead-208 is doubly magic is something of a coincidence. This point is emphasized by the familiar uranium-238 decay chain ending with lead-206 which is also stable (the alpha and beta decay mechanisms commonly seen in radioactive decay of heavy elements favor the mass number remaining congruent modulo 4).

It becomes evident that "doubly magic" has only limited utility in deciding nuclear stability. Scientists who are seeking such nuclei among superheavy isotopes are (or at least should be) cautious about predicting their actual stability against radioactive decay.